Maximum number of summands in an indecomposable decomosition.
Let $R$ be a Noetherian commutative ring and $M$ be a finitely generated $R$-module. Then there exists $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $M\cong \bigoplus_{i=1}^n M_i$, where each $M_i$ is indecomposable.
If $M$ is also Artinian (so that $M$ has finite length), then this value of $n$ is unique by Krull-Schmidt. My question is if $M$ is not Artinian what can we say about $n$? Is there a maximum to the number of summands in an indecomposable decomposition of $M$, or is it possible that one can always find a finite, but larger, decomposition? That is, is $\sup\left\{n\in\mathbb N\mid M\cong\bigoplus_{i=1}^n M_i\right\},$ where each $M_i$ is indecomposable, finite?
